# Error when creating a new opportunity with the following trigger

Tags: trigger, error

trigger StatusClosedWon on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

```
Set<Id> oppid = new Set<Id>();

 for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
{
        if(opp.StageName != trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won')
    {
     
        oppid.add(opp.Id);
        
        List<OpportunityFieldHistory> history = [Select Opportunity.Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate,
        Field, NewValue, OldValue from OpportunityFieldHistory Where Field = 'StageName' AND Opportunity.Id IN :oppid];


    for(OpportunityFieldHistory h : history)
    {
    if(h.OldValue == 'Closed Won')
    {
        opp.addError('Opportunity cannot be set to Closed Won twice!');     
    }
         }

    }
     
        
}
```

}

Error:
StatusClosedWon: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.StatusClosedWon: line 8, column 1

Comment: Please take a [tour] of the site guidelines and read thru [ask]. Questions asked on this forum should be focus on specific problem you are facing and should show some effort from your end. This seems to be a duplicate of the following question? [I want to adderror on the opportunity when past value of field history is Closed won. How to do that?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329950/i-want-to-adderror-on-the-opportunity-when-past-value-of-field-history-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this statement:

*" if(opp.StageName != trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') "*

here "trigger.oldMap" will be empty or null when the opportunity record is getting created for the first time. Hence when you say "**trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName**" it would be evaluated as **null.get(opp.Id).StageName** and is expected to throw an attempt to de-reference a null Object exception.

So if you change that line to:

*" if(trigger.oldMap!=null && opp.StageName != trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName && opp.StageName == 'Closed Won') "*

This should work fine.